# NLTK RegEx Chunker - Wildcard match any POS tag?

Tags: regex, python-2.7, nlp, nltk

I'm using NLTK's RegexpParser to get phrases from POS-tagged words. For example:

```
grammar = """
        FOUND:{<NNP>+<CD>+<,>+<CD>}
        ...
        """

pos_tagged_words = [('February', 'NNP'), ('14', 'CD'), (',', ','), ('1993', 'CD')]

result = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar).parse(pos_tagged_words)
```

Is there any way to match a wildcard tag? If this worked, I'd be looking for something like this:

```
FOUND:{<NNP>?<.>*<VBZ>}
```

Where <.> is the wildcard.

EDIT:
Found a pretty bad way to do it that doesnt really include all characters. Would still appreciate a dedicated wildcard char.

```
FOUND:{<NNP>?<[A-Z]+|[:punct:]+>*<VBZ>}
```

Comment: Can you not replace `<[A-Z]+|[:punct:]+>*` with `<.*?>` or something similar? `.` usually stands for non-newline characters, but I'm not sure with NLTK's RegexpParser.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
{<NNP>?<.*>*<VBZ>}
```